# Generate AES Key and Encode it to Base 64 String

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

I need to generate an AES key and send it to the server.

Creating the key doesn't seem to be a problem:

```
   var aesProvider = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcbPkcs7);

   var aesKey = aesProvider.CreateSymmetricKey(CryptographicBuffer.GenerateRandom(16));
```

However, exporting the AES key to a base64 encoded string seemes impossible;

I've tried exporting it using the Export/ExportPublic methods on the key object, but they all throw NotImplemented exception:

```
 aesKey.ExportPublicKey(); not implemented
 aesKey.ExportPublicKey(CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.BCryptPublicKey);
 aesKey.ExportPublicKey(CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Capi1PublicKey);
 aesKey.Export();
 aesKey.Export(CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.BCryptPrivateKey);
 aesKey.Export(CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPrivateKey);
 aesKey.Export(CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.Pkcs8RawPrivateKeyInfo);
 aesKey.Export(CryptographicPrivateKeyBlobType.Capi1PrivateKey);
```

Comment: `System.Convert.ToBase64String()` and `System.Convert.ToBase64CharArray()` ?

Comment: They work with arrays. The data is 'locked' inside the CryptographicKey object. The export method was supposed to export a buffer which I in turn could transform to a byte array and finally to a base64 encoded stream.